# Scala-Gson Deserialization: Attempted to deserialize a java.lang.Class. Forgot to register a type adapter?

Tags: json, scala, yaml, gson, deserialization

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to deserialize a java.lang.Class. Forgot to register a type adapter?`

I get that error message as I am trying to use gson deserialization in scala. i am new to scala

I have an abstract class

```
abstract class Pie() {
//does something
}
```

I also have another class

```
class Apple (val apple: someclass) extends makeApplePie {
// does something
}
class Peach (val peach: someclass) extends makePeachPie{
//does something
}
```

the abstract class makeApplePie

```
abstract class makeApplePie extends Pie{
//does something
}
abstract class makePeachPie extends Pie{
    //does something
    }

def getTypeOfPieFromString (test:String): Class[_ <: Pie]= {
    test match {
      case "Apple" => classOf[makeApplePie]
      case "Peach" => classOf[makePeachPie]
      case _=> classOf[makeApplePie]
}}
```

so I want receive some input from a yaml file and i am using gson.json to parse the input to scala

I dont know what kind of fruit will be added by user so I am using `Class [_ <: Pie]`
The question is how will i register typeAdapter for a `Class[_ <:Pie]`

```
new GsonBuilder().
    registerTypeAdapter(
    class[_ <:Pie],
    new JsonDeserializer[_ <:Pie] {
      override def deserialize(jsonElement: JsonElement, type: Type, context:JsonDeserializationContext): Class [_ <: Pie] = {
           val name = jsonElement.getAsString
           //some function that gets class makeApplePie or makePeachPie
      getTypeOfPieFromString(name)

    }

}
)
```

this is where parsing is done

```
case class howManyPie (pieType : [_ <:Pie])
case class PieInput(InputPieType: java.util.HashMap[String, howManyPie ])

// some parsing is done

 val bakePie = new startPie(
//takes in a list in case user wants to bake multiple pies 
      pies = JavaConverters.iterableAsScalaIterable(pieInput.inputPieType.values()).toList)
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: `class Apple (apple) extends makeApplePie {` is not really Scala; can you provide proper code you're working on?

Comment: `class Apple (val apple: someclass) extends makeAppleie {` I tried to replicate the details as much as I can.